# Missing numbering.xml in getOoxml()

Tags: javascript, office-js, word-addins

When using getOoxml() to get the document xml, the numbering.xml package is not included:

```
Word.run(function (context) {
     var body = context.document.body;
     var contentXML= body.getOoxml();

     return context.sync().then(function () {
           console.log("Body OOXML contents: " + contentXML.value);
     });
})
```

The word/styles.xml, word/fontTable.xml, theme1.xml, etc. are included but without the numbering.xml I cann't recreate the number formats.!

Comment: I can't reproduce this. The OOXML returned by your code does include the `<pkg:part pkg:name="/word/numbering.xml"`. It is between the `<pkg:part pkg:name="/word/settings.xml" ` and the `<pkg:part pkg:name="/word/styles.xml"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is problem in office 2016 when upgrade it to 2019 the problem has been solved

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution of your problem. Next time remember to specifiy the software/tools version in your Question.